# How to prove the constant's power x series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, taylor-expansion, irrational-numbers

Considering $k,x\in \mathbb{R}, k^x=1+\sum_{n=1^{\infty\frac{x^n(\ln(k))^n}{n!}$.
Does it have an elementary proof?

I attempt to solve by Maclaurin Series:
$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$.
It is well known that the $n$th derivatives of the function $k^x$ are $\frac{d}{dx}k^x=k^x\ln (k)$; $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}k^x=k^x(\ln(k))^2$ and, consequently, $\frac{d^n}{dx^n}k^x=k^x(\ln (k))^n$.
So$k^x=\sum \frac{x^n (k^0)^{(n)}}{n!}=\sum \frac{x^n (k^0 \ln (k))^{(n)}}{n!}=\sum_0^\infty \frac{x^n (\ln (k))^n}{n!}.$

The first term, when $n=0$ is $1$. Therefore, all the summation may be rewritten as $1+\sum_1^\infty \frac{x^n (\ln(k))^n}{n!}$.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What definition do you have for $k^x$?

Comment: @EthanBolker, $k^x=f(x)$ is the function constant to the x power or just the any potenciation's value in real numbers ($k,x \in \mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 1):

Notice $k^x=e^{\ln(k^x)}=e^{x{\ln(k)}}$ by exponent rules, and the taylor series for $e^x$ gives rise to this identity. The 1 term arises from n=0 in the taylor series for $e^x.$ If $k^x$ is complex you can take the principal branch of the logarithm, which will give the same answer for the complex series of $e^x$

Comment: Sure. If I'm not mistaken in my calculus, with some algebric manipulations and change of variable (let's call $\ln (k)=z$), it may be rewritten as:
$$1-e^z=-ze^z+ze^z\sum_{n\geq 2} \frac{(-1)^n z^n }{n!}$$.